# Sideways table not centered in the page

Tags: tables, rotating, landscape

I'm writing a paper in the format of Monthly Notices of the Royal Astronomical Society (MNRAS). I have several tables I need landscaped since they are too wide. I have used the sideways table command and although the table is landscaped it's flushed heavily to the left with half the table not visible. [image: Screenshot of error]

The Preamble to my paper is this

```
    \documentclass[useAMS,usenatbib]{mn2e}
    %\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{article} %showframe

    % set up sensible margins (same as for cssethesis)
    %\usepackage[paper=a4paper,left=30mm,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm]      {geometry}

    %\usepackage{setspace} % Word spacing
    %\singlespacing %(or \doublespacing  \onehalfspacing)

    \usepackage{txfonts}

    \usepackage{mathtools} % can add [fleqn]: fleqn argument shifts equations to the left rather than centred
    \usepackage{amssymb} % adds math symbols easily 
     \usepackage[load-configurations=astronomy]{siunitx} % astro symbols made easy. eg: \num{2e-4} \si{\kilo\metre} \SI{2e-4}{\kilo\metre\per\second}

     \DeclareSIUnit\parsec{pc}
      \DeclareSIUnit\kilo{K}
       \DeclareSIUnit\ergs{ergs}
       \usepackage[version=3]{mhchem} % chem symbols made easy eg: \ce{H20}
        %\numberwithin{equation}{section} %gives eqns as 1.1 in section 1 and 2.1 in section 2 and so on. 

     \usepackage{graphicx} % Helps with graphics and tables 
      %\usepackage[width=0.8\textwidth]{caption} % justification=centering,Captions on figures labelfont=bf,font=it,
     \usepackage{float}
      \usepackage{subfigure}
       \usepackage{subcaption} %subcaptions on figures
        %\numberwithin{figure}{section}

       \usepackage{titlesec}
        \titlespacing\section{0pt}{12pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{6pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
        \titlespacing\subsection{0pt}{12pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{6pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
         \titlespacing\subsubsection{0pt}{12pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{6pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}

         \usepackage{morefloats}

         \usepackage{lscape}
          \usepackage{pdflscape}

          %\usepackage{afterpage}
           %\newcommand\blankpage{%
            %\null
           %\thispagestyle{empty}%
           %\addtocounter{page}{-1}%
           %\newpage}


           \usepackage{color}

             %\usepackage{pdfpages}

              \usepackage{perpage} %the perpage package
               \MakePerPage{footnote} %the perpage package command


                 \usepackage [author year, colon, round]{natbib}                
                 %\usepackage{bibtex} % Use the natbib bibliography and citation package (author, year style, with round brackets)
                  \usepackage{hyperref} % hyperlinks to reference

              \usepackage{booktabs} 
              \usepackage{multirow}
              \usepackage{array}
              \usepackage{longtable}
               \usepackage{tabu}
                \usepackage{threeparttable} %table with notes
                 \usepackage{threeparttablex} %longtable with notes
                 \usepackage{rotating}
                  \usepackage{xtab}
                   \usepackage{multicol}

                  \usepackage[title,titletoc,toc]{appendix} % \appendix



            %\newcommand{\sol}[1]{\odot{#1}} % short code for sun symbol 
            % {$\mathrm{}$} = Math mode in non-italized form
             \newcommand{\textsubscript}[1]{$_\textrm{#1}$} %short code for subscripting
              \newcommand{\Ha}{H${\alpha}$} % short code for H-alpha
               \newcommand{\HB}{H$\beta$} % short code for H-beta
               \newcommand{\EHaHB}{E(H$\alpha$-H$\beta$)} % short code for E(Ha-HB)
                \newcommand{\CHa} {C$_{{\textrm{H}\alpha}}$} % short code for CHa
                 \newcommand{\CHB}{C$_{{\textrm{H}\beta}}$} % short code for CH-beta
                  \newcommand{\AV}{$\textrm{A}_{\textrm{V}}$} % short code for Av
                   \newcommand{\Av}{$\textrm{A}_{\textrm{V}}$} % short code for Av
                  \newcommand{\AvCHB}{A_{\textrm{V}}(\textrm{C}$_{{\textrm{H}\beta}}$)} % short code for Av(CH-beta)
                   \newcommand{\AvCHa}{A_{\textrm{V}}(\textrm{C}$_{{\textrm{H}\alpha}}$)} % short code for Av(CH-alpha)
                \newcommand{\AvE}{A_{\textrm{V}}[\textrm{E}(\textrm{H}$\alpha$-\textrm{H}$\beta$)]} % short code for E(Ha-HB)
                 \newcommand{\app}[1]{\textup{\textsc{\MakeLowercase{#1}}}}
                  \newcommand{\comm}[1]{\texttt{#1}}

             \title[}
             \author[]
             \date{Received:}

             \begin{document}

              \maketitle

               \begin{abstract}
                   .....
                \end{abstract}

               \begin{keywords}
                 ......
                \end{keywords}


                \input{./Tables/Table1}


                %\include{Appendix}


                 \bibliographystyle{chicago}
                  \bibliography{fullbib}
                   \end{document}
```

The Table Code is this:

```
      \begin{sidewaystable*}
      \centering
      \caption [Table 1]{Table 1}
      \label{Table 1}
          \begin{threeparttable}
           \begin{tabular}{lllllllp{1.5cm}p{1.3cm}p{1.3cm}p{1.3cm}p{1.5cm}l}
               \toprule
                \textbf{} & \textbf{} & \textbf{} & \textbf{} &     \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{CCD Data}} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Aperture Radii}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Source Intensity}} \\
                 \cmidrule(lr){5-7}
                  \cmidrule(lr){8-11}
                   \cmidrule(lr){12-13}
                   \textbf{PN Name} & \textbf{RA} & \textbf{Dec} &  \textbf{Run} & \textbf{CCD} & \textbf{X} & \textbf{Y} & \textbf{Shape} &  \textbf{Centroid} & \textbf{Inner Sky} & \textbf{Outer Sky} & \textbf{intensity  (counts)} & \textbf{unc.} \\   
                    (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) & (5) & (6) & (7) & (8) & (9) & (10) & (11) & (12) & (13)\\
                       \midrule
                      PN G119.64+03.2 & 00:19:09.79 & +65:53:26.00 & 414 153  & 4     & 539   & 743   & C     & 4     & 9     & 14    & 1013.10 & 38.87 \\
                      &       &       & 414551 & 2     & 1968  & 1612  &        &       &       &       & 1050.30 & 43.22 \\
      &       &       & 414554 & 2     & 1061  & 2513  &       &       &       &       & 1075.10 & 38.98 \\
PN G121.68+03.6 & 00:38:54.00 & +66:23:49.00 & 417705 & 3     & 1124  & 795   & C     & 41    & 47    & 52    & 128616.00 & 1154.20 \\
      &       &       & 418383 & 2     & 1832  & 99    &       &       &       &       & 155089.00 & 930.89 \\
      &       &       & 419386 & 2     & -     & -     &       &       &       &       & 157573.00 & 931.57 \\
PN G126.30+02.9 & 01:24:58.60 & +65:38:36.00 & 367533 & 3     & 1305  & 249   & C     & 24    & 27    & 30    & 326749.00 & 1057.60 \\
      &       &       & 703469 & 4     & 354   & 3756  &       &       &       &       & 317515.00 & 1069.20 \\
      &       &       & 703472 & 2     & 1562  & 1191  &       &       &       &       & 309835.00 & 1017.60 \\
PN G126.60+01.3 & 01:25:07.90 & +63:56:53.00 & 367778 & 4     & 827.00 & 612.00 & E     & Maj=60 & 67    & 75    & 292152.00 & 1253.30 \\
      &       &       & 367781 & 4     & 1744.90 & 1521.70 & Rot=+28$\si{\degree}$ & Min=34 &       &       & 276108.00 & 1770.50 \\
      &       &       & 367894 & 2     & 1098.60 & 2801.60 & Rot=-46$\si{\degree}$ &       & 60    & 70    & 288338.00 & 2313.70 \\
      &       &       & 367897 & 2     & 173.80 & 3708.60 &       &       &       &       & 289128.00 & 2314.60 \\   
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}
\footnotesize
\item .......
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{sidewaystable*}
```

I have tried rotate commands and `\hspace`, `\vspace` and `\newgeometry{margin=1cm}` but none of it seems to work. How do I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. I looks like the `mn2e` document class experiences some conflicts with the `rotating` package (which provides the `sidewaystable` environment). Here's a work-around, though not a full fix: Insert the insert the instruction `\RequirePackage{rotating}` immediately before the `\documentclass` instruction.

Comment: You also might try pdflscape which uses the built in PDF transformation matrix.

Comment: @Mico Yes that worked perfectly!! Thank you for the answers!

Comment: @Mico You should post this as a solution.

Comment: @Andrew - Done. :-)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It looks like the `mn2e` document class experiences some conflicts with the `rotating` package (which provides the `sidewaystable` environment), or possibly with the `graphicx` package, which is loaded by the `rotating` package.

A workround -- not a complete fix, for sure -- consists of inserting the instruction

```
\RequirePackage{rotating}
```

*before* the `\documentclass` instruction.

With this setup, your table in your sample document is placed correctly.

Comment: Had the same problem with the `acmart` class and this solved the problem. Thanks!