# Sideways Figure doesn't center

Tags: rotating, sidewaysfigure

I am trying to rotate a figure on the page by 90 degrees. I am using:

```
\usepackage{rotating}
```

and then my figure code looks like:

```
\begin{sidewaysfigure*}[ht]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{@{}cc@{}}
    \includegraphics[width=120mm]{c1713_a_vm.png} &
    \includegraphics[width=120mm]{c1713_b_vm.png}
  \end{tabular}                                       
  \caption{figure caption}
  \label{fig_label}
\end{sidewaysfigure*}
```

This produces a figure that seems to be hugging the left hand side, and missing half of the caption. I want to center it horizontally (as you view it), but I'm not sure how to do this.

I have found a similar problem [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/239444/sideways-table-not-centered-in-the-page), and apparently the problem here is the "mn2e" document class (for an astrophysical journal). I'm not using that class, but I am using a class for a different astrophysics journal ("emulateapj"), which seems like a bit of a coincidence! The remedy suggested was to put:

```
\RequirePackage{rotating}
```

before the \documentclass instruction. But when I try this, it doesn't solve my problem and I get the following error:

```
*** BUG ***
In pixman_region32_init_rect: Invalid rectangle passed
Set a breakpoint on '_pixman_log_error' to debug
```

[image]

---

MWE:

```
\documentclass{emulateapj}
\newcommand{\vdag}{(v)^\dagger}
\newcommand\aastex{AAS\TeX}
\newcommand\latex{La\TeX}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,etoolbox}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tabularx,colortbl}
\usepackage{adjustbox}\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\setstackEOL{\cr}                                                        
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaysfigure*}[ht]                                                                                                                                                                
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{@{}cc@{}}
    \includegraphics[width=120mm]{1713_a_vm.png} &
    \includegraphics[width=120mm]{1713_b_vm.png}
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Figure caption figure caption figure caption.}
  \label{1713_vm}                                                                                                                                                                                             
\end{sidewaysfigure*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please always post a complete MWE, not code fragments, otherwise helpers have to guess what is happening and make best guess suggestions.

Comment: Try \vspace*{\fill} \begin{adjustbox} {angle=90,center,nofloat=table} .... \end{adjustbox}\vspace*{\fill}, obviously after adding \usepackage{adjustbox}

Comment: Thanks. I've added a MWE now. I tried your suggestion. It was still off the page but I'm not sure if I was putting it in the right place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default format for `apj` is `twocolumn`. It can be set to one column with the class option `\documentclass[onecolumn]{emulateapj}`. Indeed, if this class option is chosen, the two figures are centered horizontally on the page.

The starred variant `sidewaysfigure*` is intended to switch the `sidewaysfigure` environment from two column to one column. However, with the default class option set to `twocolumn`, the sideways table remains in the first (left) column on a two column page.

One column can be enforced by invoking `\onecolumngrid` before the `sidewaystable` environment. I also changed `sidewaysfigure*` to `sidewaystable*` since you are putting a table in the sideways environment rather than a figure.

You can get the `Figure` prefix for the caption by adding `\usepackage{capt-of}` and using `\captionof{figure}{my caption}`. Note it is not possible to use `\captionof` from the `caption` package. Loading the caption package generates many errors, presumably due to clashes with what is happening inside the `emulateapj` class file.

This is the result, with the `showframe` option added to `geometry` to show the positioning.:

[image]

This is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{emulateapj}
\newcommand{\vdag}{(v)^\dagger}
\newcommand\aastex{AAS\TeX}
\newcommand\latex{La\TeX}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,etoolbox}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{rotating}
%\usepackage{longtable}
%\usepackage{caption}
%\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{tabularx,colortbl}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\setstackEOL{\cr}                                                        
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\onecolumngrid

\begin{sidewaystable*}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}cc@{}}
    \includegraphics[width=0.45\textheight]{example-image-a} &
    \includegraphics[width=0.45\textheight]{example-image-a}
  \end{tabular}
  \captionof{figure}{ caption figure caption figure caption.}
  \label{1713_vm}
\end{sidewaystable*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can use `\figcaption{caption figure}` and so you don't need the caption package that causes the errors.

Comment: @koleygr. Thanks. Maybe what I wrote wasn't clear. I used `\captionof` from the `capt-of` package. I rewrote that part of the answer.

Comment: Ok. Didn't noticed that. Nice (You already have +1 from me I am not deleting my answer just because somebody else (other document class) will find it useful.)

Answer (score 1):

You can try without `sidewaysfigure` just using tikz package like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}

\pagebreak
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[rotate=-90] at (0,0) {\begin{minipage}{0.98\textheight}
                   \begin{center}
                   I'd like to rotate this page
                   \end{center}
                   \blindtext

                   \centering
                   \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-a}
                      \captionof{figure}{Test caption}
                \end{minipage}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Also you can see my answer here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/392793/120578
if you wish to rotate the pdf page too

Comment: Thanks. But when I use my \documentclass{emulateapj}, this no longer works unfortunately.